# How to transfer a table column values to a one column table?

Tags: java, jtable

I have two tables, one with 4 columns and the other with one column, How could we copy the values the second column of the first table to the table with one column in Java.
 I tried this algorithm (tab1 is the one column table, tab2 is the 4 columns table)

```js
int i=0;
JTable tab1=null;
for ( i=1;i<colnumber;i++)
  
  {
    tab1[i][1]=tab2.getValueAt(i,2);
}
```

but it returns "illegal start of expression " error.
So how can I transfer a table column values to a one column table, and what is wrong with my code?

Comment: 1. why do you set tab1 null? 2. why do you set in the loop initialization i=1 ? 3. you can't take indices of JTable it's not an array

Comment: in which line is the illegal start of expression?

Comment: My gut tells me trying to set a value in a null JTable is the source of your problems. You should use `JTable(int numrows, int numcolums)` to initialize `tab1`. Have you checked the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#JTable-int-int-)?

Comment: 1) I set tab1 null to initialize it, because it didnt exist before.2) I would start transfering the content starting  with the first line.3) I thought a JTable is the same as an Array.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the data in the table then you change the data in the `TableModel`, not in an Array. You do this be invoking the `setValueAt()` method of the `JTable` (or the `TableModel`):

```
for (int i = 0; i < table2.getRowCount(); i++)
{
    Object value = table2.getValueAt(i, ?);
    table1.setValueAt(value, i, ?);
}
```